# Dynamic row addition at the bottom of Table in IE

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, internet-explorer

Based on the button click event, I want to add rows dynamically at the bottom of an existing table.

I had done the same using Javascript which is given below. It is working fine in Chrome browser whereas in IE the rows are getting added at the top rather than at the bottom.

If I click the button multiple times then could see that all the rows are getting added at the top one after the other in IE.

```
function addRow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

    var rowCount = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr").length;

    var row = tbody.insertRow(-1);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    cell1.classList.add("PadLeft10");
    cell1.classList.add("PadBottom5");
    cell1.classList.add("textcenter");
    cell1.width = "2%";
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    element1.name = "element1[" + index + "].selected";
    element1.id = "element1[" + index + "].selected";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);
    [...]
}
```

I could see in the docs that tbody.insertRow(-1) should append row at the last in both IE and Chrome, but for me in IE it is getting added at the top. I tried many ways but in all it works fine in Chrome but not in IE.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `insertRow` part is the problem, you can do this to reliably add to the end instead:

```
var row = document.createElement("tr");
tbody.appendChild(row);
```

Similarly, `var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);` (if it is also a problem) can be:

```
var cell1 = document.createElement("tr");
row.insertBefore(cell1, row.firstChild);
```

Finally, MDN says that IE has long supported [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) (all the way back to IE4), so that entire method could be replaced with the following if you like:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tbody = table.querySelector("tbody");
    var rowCount = table.querySelectorAll("tr").length; // Or: `= table.rows.length;`

    // ***Where does `index` come from? Did you mean `rowCount`?
    var name = "element1[" + index + "].selected";
    var html =
        '<tr>' +
            '<td class="PadLeft10 PadBottom5 textcenter" width="2%">' +
                '<input type="checkbox" name="' + name + '" id="' + name + '">' +
            '</td>' +
        '</tr>';

    tbody.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
    // ...
}
```